# Pandas: change the order of a column based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I got a Pandas `DataFrame` which has three columns. Two of which (column1 and column2) has the same content.

```
column1 column2 column3
Apple   Huawei  111
Huawei  Sumsung 222
Sumsung Apple   333
```

I want to change the order of column2 and column3 based on column1. Column3 changes with Column2

```
column1 column2 column3
Apple   Apple   333
Huawei  Huawei  111
Sumsung Sumsung 222
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Why is [Samsung](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung) misspelled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set values of `column3` by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by `column2` and then overwrite `column2` by `column1`:

*Notice: For correct working is necessary same unique values in `column2` like `column1` in another order.*

```
df = df.assign(column3 = df['column1'].map(df.set_index('column2')['column3']),
               column2 = df['column1'])
print (df)
   column1  column2  column3
0    Apple    Apple      333
1   Huawei   Huawei      111
2  Sumsung  Sumsung      222
```

Answer (score 1):

[jezrael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65788411/pandas-change-the-order-of-a-column-based-on-another-column/65788489#65788489) is correct. But I have a more general (probably not faster) solution. This is better when you have more than three columns, say column4, column5, ..., column100.

```py
s = df['column1']
df = df.iloc[:,1:].set_index('column2')
df = df.loc[s].reset_index()
```

```
>>> df
   column2  column3
0    Apple      333
1   Huawei      111
2  Sumsung      222
```